# My messages are delivered out of flow sequence order and how do I compensate?

Tags: json, twilio

I wish to use Twilio in the context of an adventure game.  As the gamer (Geocacher) progresses on an actual treasure (cache)  hunt, clues are given by text when certain code words or numbers are entered as part of the thread.  I am very comfortable creating the flow in Studio and have a working flow that is debugged and ready to go.

Not so fast, grasshopper!  Strange things started to happen when beta testing the flow.  Basically texts that show as being sent arrive to the user out of sequence in the thread.  The SM logs show everything is working correctly (message sent) but, what I call Zombie messages arrive to the user after a previous message has arrived.  The Zombies are legitimate messages from the Flow but out of the correct sequence and that makes the thread unusable for my purposes.

I learned too late in my "programming" that Twilio states, "If you send multiple SMS messages to the same user in a short time, Twilio cannot guarantee that those messages will arrive in the order that you sent them."  Ugh!

So , I started with the Help Techs at Twillio and one solution is to create a subflow that basically is inserted after a Send Message Widget.  This sub flow basically Fetches the message via the SMS SID to check for SMS status. If status is "delivered", we can safely say the message has been received by the recipient and then permit the next message in the flow.

That sound great but I am not a programmer and will never be able to integrate the suggested code much less debug it when things don't work.  There might be many other approaches that you guys can suggest.  The task is 1.) Send a message, 2.) Run a subflow that checks for message delivery, 3.) send the next message in the sequence.

I need to move on to implementation and this type of sub flow is out of my wheelhouse.  I am willing to pay for programming help.

I can post the JSON code that was created as a straw man but have no idea how to use it and if it is the optimum solution if that is of help.  It would seem that a lot of folks experience this issue and would like a solution.  A nice tight JSON subflow with directions on how to insert would seem to be a necessary part of the Widget toolkit provided by Twillio in Studio.

Please Help Me! =)

Comment: OK, I am trying to follow the steps listed on this page -
https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/quickstart/add-delay

I managed to follow and paste but really don't know what I am doing. =)  I don't think I got the path correct. It currently is set to /path_1    So, I can save and "compile."

Then in Studio , I created a new flow to test.  I can select Run Function widget and sure enough under Service the name I gave the function I created shows up.  But I do not know how to fill in the Function URL dialog. 

more..

Comment: more...

I go ahead and drag into the tiny flow and connect between send message widgets.  Nothing happens - the flow stops at the delay step.  If I connect fail tab, to the next step the flow continues to execute but only because my attempt at a function just fails.

I am almost there but need a nudge, please.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, the delivery of the message cannot be guaranteed. Checking the status of the sent message is the most reliable, using a subflow, a Twilio Function, or a combination. Just keep in mind that Twilio Functions have a 10s execution time limit. I don't expect delivering the SMS will take longer than 10s is most cases. If you're worried about edge cases, you'd have to loop the check for the status multiple times. I'll share a proof of concept later for this.

An easier way, but it still doesn't guarantee delivery order, would be to add some delay between each message. There's no built-in delay widget, but here's code on [how to create a Twilio Function to add delays, up to 10s](https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/quickstart/add-delay).

A more hacky way to implement delays without having to use this Twilio Function, is to use the [Send & Wait For Reply Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/send-wait-reply) and configure the "Stop Gathering After" property to the amount of delay you'd like to add. If the user responds, connect to the next widget, if they don't also connect to the widget.

---

As mentioned earlier, here's th Subflow + Function proof of concept I hacked together:

First, create a Twilio Functions Service, in the service create two functions:

*/delay*:

```js
// Helper function for quickly adding await-able "pauses" to JavaScript
const sleep = (delay) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, delay));

exports.handler = async (context, event, callback) => {
  // A custom delay value could be passed to the Function, either via
  // request parameters or by the Run Function Widget
  // Default to a 5 second delay
  const delay = event.delay || 5000;
  // Pause Function for the specified number of ms
  await sleep(delay);
  // Once the delay has passed, return a success message, TwiML, or
  // any other content to whatever invoked this Function.
  return callback(null, `Timer up: ${delay}ms`);
};
```

*/get-message*:

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const messageSid = event.message_sid,
    client = context.getTwilioClient();
  
  if(!event.message_sid) throw "message_sid parameter is required.";

  client.messages(messageSid)
    .fetch()
    .then(message => callback(null, message))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      return callback(error);
    });
};
```

Then, create a Studio Flow named something like "Send and Wait until Delivered".
In this flow, you send the message, grabbing the message body passed in from the parent flow, `{{trigger.parent.parameters.message_body}}`.
Then, you run the `/get-message` Function, and check the message status.
If `delivered`, set `status` variable to `delivered`. This variable will be passed back to the parent flow. If any of these `accepted,queued,sending,sent`, then the message is still in route, so wait a second using the `/delay` function, then loop back to the `/get-message` function.
If any other status, it is assumed there's something wrong and `status` is set to `error`.

Now you can create your parent flow where you call the subflow, specifying the `message_body` parameter. Then you can check the `status` variable for the subflow, whether it is 'delivered' or 'error'.

You can find the export for the subflow and the parent flow in [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Swimburger/49bc868161d4536450d291c83e9c1a4b). You can import it and it could be useful as a reference.

Personally, I'd add the `/delay` function, and use that after every message, adding a couple of seconds delay. I'd personally assume the delay adds enough buffer for no zombie messages to appear.

---

Note: The code, proof of concept, and advice is offered as is without liability to me or Twilio. It is not tested against a production workload, so make sure you test this thoroughly for your use case!

Comment: Thank you Swimburger!  I embrace the idea of creating a sub flow and calling it in my Studio flow, I just haven’t wrapped my head around doing it properly.  i will study your suggestions and work toward learning those skills.

Meanwhile I used your “tacky” solution and inserted a send and respond per your suggestion with a 10 second delay.  So far in my beta testing that is accomplishing the objective of getting the messages delivered in the correct sequence.

I may contact you for further guidance as I wade into the other proposals.

Comment: OK, I am tryijng to follow the steps listed on this page -

Comment: OK, I am trying to follow the steps listed on this page -
https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/quickstart/add-delay

I managed to follow and paste but really don't know what I am doing. =)  I don't think I got the path correct. It currently is set to /path_1    So, I can save and "compile."

Then in Studio , I created a new flow to test.  I can select Run Function widget and sure enough under Service the name I gave the function I created shows up.  But I do not know how to fill in the Function URL dialog. 

more..

Comment: I go ahead and drag into the tiny flow and connect between send message widgets.  Nothing happens - the flow stops at the delay step.  If I connect fail tab, to the next step the flow continues to execute but only because my attempt at a function just fails.

I am almost there but need a nudge, please.

Comment: If I had a way to send screen shots , I think my questions would be clearer. =)

Comment: Feel free to link free image hosting platforms like imgur :) You can rename the function path by clicking on the three dots next to it, and click rename. However, the naming doesn't change the functionality, it's more for organizational purposes. If you created the function widget, selected the service, the environment as UI, and then select the URL of your delay function, it should work.
However, you do have to set the `delay` parameter to the desired time in milliseconds. No longer than 10000, probably safer to go even below that, due to the time limitation of function executions.

Comment: Make sure you have saved the function, and then click the deploy all functions button. There shouldn't be a reason for the delay function to fail, unless the configured delay is above 10000 ms.

Comment: Also, there's a logs tab which can be very helpful to inspect the parameters going in and the parameters going out of the widgets in your Studio flow.

Comment: Well I just kept plugging in parts until the motor started.  =)  So after entering the function code in the services dialog and deploying.  I copied from this line in the deployed code the part reading : message-delay-8120.twil.io
Deployed to environment: message-delay-8120.twil.io

Then back in Studio in the dialog for the Run Function widget  added the link, message-delay-8120.twil.io, into the dialog box for function url.  

Then the flow executes as expected and by changing the event delay number in the function see that I can specify the delay that will prolly work. more...

Comment: This is much better than the send and wait hack as the user could always enter something in the send field instead of letting timeout due to fail create.  Now that I kinda' see what is happening, I may get brave enough to take on the check for delivery function.  =)

Comment: That's great to hear! The delay itself will be sufficient in most cases I think :)

Comment: I cant move to chat as I have not been a member long enough.
So. I will continue the thread:

Well, I am still seeing zombie messages but at a reduced frequency thanks to the delay function call.  But any occurance ruins the experience.  =(  So, it appears the bullet-proof technique must be the "Send and Wait until Delivered" method which I am intimidated by.  I'll try to slog it out but I am going to have lean on you for serious direction. =)

Comment: I may just be better off using all send and wait for reply widgets.  Instead of delivering a message and inserting a delay (and hoping that is good enough to defeat zombies) before posting the next message(which is a send and wait widget,) 

I can ask the receiver to acknowledge the receipt  with a reply which would force no zombies I think. =)   Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, asking for a reply will definitely work. I could provide an alternative Function that checks the message every second until the time limit is reached. This may be simpler than using a subflow, but if the message is delivered after 9-10s, the Function will have timed out probably. This amount of time may be fine tho for most cases.